# Tab/TabGroup click event not firing when the tab is selected Ti SDK 5.2.0, Android SDK 23

Tags: android, tabs, click, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to include a feature where when a tab is Home Tab is selected and user clicks on it again the Feed scrolls to top like Twitter.
However bot Tab and Tab Group fire click event only when clicking on an unselected Tab. Once the Tab is selected for some reason the event is not fired. Any Solutions?
Ti SDK 5.2.0
Android SDK 23

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding listener with your tab and listen for click event. Ther are other events also that you can track. [Documentation Link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Tab)

```
tab.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    Ti.API.log("Click Tab Detected");

});
```

Comment: may be right. Then in the tab handler function you can check the e.source. If it was fired from your Home tab, you call your method to refresh it =)

Comment: I have tried....I get the click event when i navigate between tabs...However when i am on TAB A and then again click TAB A the click event doesn't get fired...I think this is a bug

Comment: If you think this is a bug you can create a Jira ticket with test code. https://jira.appcelerator.org/